# How can I get Javascript results to show up in the Order Review section of the Onepage Checkout?

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.7, checkout, review

Hello I'm having trouble getting `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` display in the template/checkout/onepage/review/review.phtml or even the template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml. In fact the only place I can get a script tag to display is in the template/checkout/onepage/onepage.phtml.

Can anyone explain to me what I can do to get script tags to show up in the Order Review section? I need to add these scripts so I can tag orders for tracking.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento will not strip out script tags so it is quite possible that you are editing the wrong template. [Turn on template path hints](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-) to get the right file then insert the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your template must have been overriden by some other modules template files.
BTW script tags are not written in template files. This causes many issues some of which I have personally faced

Include script tag in layout.xml using addJs in head or footer reference

But if you still want to include script in js see the current template file from the template path shown by fkim

Comment: I too prefer this, but sometimes you want to run scripts once the template is brought in, and it can often be easier to just add the script in the called template file.  But the script tags seem to be getting stripped out.

Comment: Disagree. `<script>` is most definitely used in template files. Magento does this out of the box and so do many developers. How else are you supposed to assign dynamic values to scripts?